# On select javascript not working with pull down?

Tags: javascript, html, onselect

I am new to javascript.

I have a function I modifed that when a user selects "Yes" from a pull down menu it creates 3 text boxes in a div area.

Here is my form pull down code:

```
    <select name="dosage" id="dosage" onchange="function dosage(sel)">
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option> 

    </select>
<div id="dosagearea"></div>
```

This is the javascript I modified which originally created a message box to the user when they selected something.

```
    function dosage(sel)
{
   if(sel.options.selectedIndex == 0)
   {

      return false;
   }


    else if(sel.options.selectedIndex == 'Yes')
       {
          x=document.createElement('input');
                    x.setAttribute('rows',1);
                    x.setAttribute('cols',20);
                    x.name='dosage_emitted';
                    document.getElementById('dosagearea').appendChild(x);

            x=document.createElement('input');
                    x.setAttribute('rows',1);
                    x.setAttribute('cols',20);
                    x.name='dosage_absorbed';
                    document.getElementById('dosagearea').appendChild(x)


            x=document.createElement('input');
                    x.setAttribute('rows',1);
                    x.setAttribute('cols',20);
                    x.name='dosage_period';
                    document.getElementById('dosagearea').appendChild(x)
       }
    }
```

I checked with firebug and no JS errors being returned, I think my function is not being called the right way.

Thanks

Comment: you also don't need to add rows attribute. that's for textarea tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the onchange property is basically the name of a function or some JavaScript. If you want to call your function with the select element as a parameter, you need to do

```
<select name="dosage" id="dosage" onchange="dosage(this)">
```

Note that this isn't the recommended way to do things as it couples your HTML with your JS. Instead, try adding the event directly in JS, like so

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("dosage").onchange = dosage;
    function dosasage(event) {
        var sel = event.currentTarget;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried what you suggested but it says this in firebug:

document.getElementById("dosage").onchange = dosage; 

Error: document.getElementById("dosage") is null

Comment: You might be calling your JavaScript before the DOM is ready. Try putting the code I mentioned in a window.onload function. I updated my example.

Answer (score 0):

try the following: `onchange="dosage(this)"`

Comment: Thanks but now firebug says Error: dosage is not a function

Answer (score 0):

it's better to have the fields already in html with display:none either on the inputs or the placeholder. and toggle to display:block when `yes` is selected. Also, you need to change the event listener to  onchange="dosage(this)"

or make it like this

```
<select name="dosage" id="dosage" onchange="document.getElementById('dosagearea').style.display = this.options.selectedIndex ? 'block' : 'none'">
   <option value="No">No</option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option> 
</select>
<div id="dosagearea" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="dosage_emitted" />
    <input type="text" name="dosage_absorbed" />
    <input type="text" name="dosage_period" />
</div>
```

here it is in action http://jsfiddle.net/t4cy7/

Comment: Thanks I like your way much better, it is simple and localised to the page.

You are the winner!